# chdir(..) returns 0 for success and changes directory, but outputs "No such file or directory"

Tags: c, string, pointers, cd, chdir

I'm implementing `cd` functionality using system calls in a C program that acts as a simple shell, and am having a bit of an issue with directory names. I have a feeling it's trivially string related, but I haven't had any luck so far.

I have a function like the following:

```
static void parse_args(int argc, char **argv) {

    // Special conditions:
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "return") == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "cd") == 0) {

        if (strcmp(argv[2], "mydir") == 0) {
            printf("Directory name is 'mydir'!\n");
        } else {
            printf("Directory name is NOT 'mydir'!\n");
        }

        int ret = chdir(argv[2]);
        if (ret == 0) { // success
            printf("Able to change directory.\n");
        } else {
            printf("UNABLE to change directory.\n");
        }
    }

    // Handling piping for shell ....
}
```

I know up front that `argv[2]` is a string containing my new desired directory.

I wish to `cd` into an existing directory called `mydir`, and call `changeDirectory` with `argv[2]` equal to `"mydir"`. However, as you can see, inside `changeDirectory`, I verify that `argv[2]` is in fact exactly equal to "mydir".

The results of my simple shell call is:

```
$> pwd
/foo/bar
$> cd mydir
Directory name is 'mydir'!
UNABLE to change directory.
/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: mydir: No such file or directory
$> pwd
/foo/bar/mydir
```

So it appears the command succeeds, however I don't know why I'm receiving the error message.
**Interestingly, this error message doesn't occur if I call `int ret = chdir("mydir");`**
Can I cast/sanitize this parameter somehow? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Can I san

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the output, please show the actual code. And you're not printing the error message somewhere else?

Comment: Already seen this question or something very, very similar. `chdir` does not call an external `/usr/bin/cd`. Find the place in your code that's calling that and fix it.

Comment: What is `/usr/bin/cd`? Some systems do have such a command, but it's nearly pointless -- and the code you've shown us doesn't invoke it.

Comment: Agh, I had forgotten to exit the function after changing the directory. Consequently, I was trying to later perform an `execvp` with `cd` as a parameter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had forgotten to exit the function after changing the directory. Later in the function, I was passing `cd` as a parameter to `execvp` to execute it as if it were a program. Simply encapsulating the later "Handle Piping" code in an `else` resolved this.